# ReactJS can't set state from an event with event.persist()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to set a state field which I get from an event, but it doesn't get set when I pass a function to it. The component and method looks like the following:

```
constructor(props: SomeProps, context: any) {
  super(props, context);
  this.state = {
    isFiltering: props.isFiltering,
    anchor: "",
  };
}

private toggleFilter = (event: any) => {
  event.persist()
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    isFiltering: !prevState.isFiltering,
    anchor: event.currentTarget // does not work, it's null
  }));
}
```

If I remove `event.persist()` then I get the following error :

> This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `currentTarget` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling for more information.

For some reason the following code works:

```
private toggleFilter = (event: any) => {
  this.setState({anchor:event.currentTarget}) // works fine
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    isFiltering: !prevState.isFiltering,
  }));
}
```

Why does the above works but not when I use `this.setState(prevState=> ...)`?

Comment: I think it's because `setState` is "async", so by the time the function you pass to `setState` is executed (and the event is accessed), the event is no longer around. In the second version, the event is accessed immediately and its `currentTarget` passed to `setState`.

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks that makes sense, however it seems `event.persist()` is the appropriate solution for this, but it does kinda not work for me..

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure why it doesn't work (without testing it myself), so I didn't write an answer.

Comment: @thirtydot Thx for the comment, I got a working solution.

Comment: You are storing DOM element in state? Hm.. Maybe not the best idea.

Comment: @dfsq It's only one component as a Popover. Should be fine for that or? [This is the one](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/popover)

Comment: Should be fine 

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use this? `private toggleFilter = (event: any) => {
 this.setState({
  isFiltering: !this.state.isFiltering,
  anchor: event.currentTarget
 });
}`. Probably easier to understand.

Comment: @thirtydot It's over simplified. More stuff is happening.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**That's the expected behaviour**, because `event.persist()` doesn't imply that `currentTarget` is not being nullified, in fact it should be - that's compliant with browser's native implementation.

This means that if you want to access currentTarget in async way, you need to cache it in a variable as you did in your answer.

---

To cite one of the React core developers - [Sophie Alpert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49485/sophie-alpert).

> currentTarget changes as the event bubbles up – if you had a event handler on the element receiving the event and others on its ancestors, they'd see different values for currentTarget. IIRC nulling it out is consistent with what happens on native events; if not, let me know and we'll reconsider our behavior here.

Check out [the source](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2857) of the discussion in the official React repository and the following snippet provided by Sophie that I've touched a bit.

```js
var savedEvent;
var savedTarget;

divb.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  savedEvent = e;
  savedTarget = e.currentTarget;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('b: currentTarget is now ' + e.currentTarget);
  }, 0);
}, false);

diva.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('same event object? ' + (e === savedEvent));
  console.log('same target? ' + (savedTarget === e.currentTarget));
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('a: currentTarget is now ' + e.currentTarget);
  }, 0);
}, false);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 50px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="diva"><div id="divb"> Click me and see output! </div></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 23):

With the comment from @thirtydot I got a working solution.

> I think it's because setState is "async", so by the time the function you pass to setState is executed (and the event is accessed), the event is no longer around. In the second version, the event is accessed immediately and its currentTarget passed to setState

So I stored the `event.currentTarget` to a variable and used that as it's explained in the [ReactJs Event Pooling](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

Looks like this and it works

```
private toggleFilter = (event: any) => {
        let target = event.currentTarget;   
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            isFiltering: !prevState.isFiltering,
            anchor: target
        }));
    }
```

However this does not explain why `event.persist()` is not working. I'll accept the answer which explains it.

Answer (score 9):

To resolve this issue - before calling handleSubmit of form, call 
event.persist() and then in handleSubmit() definition - write your logic. For e.g.

```
<form id="add_exp_form" onSubmit={(event) => {event.persist();this.handleSubmit(event)}}>

handleSubmit(event){
    // use event.currentTarget - It will be visible here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your function you should use const     `event.preventDefault()` or     `event.prevent()`

example:

```
updateSpecs1 = (event) => { 
    event.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across similar warning message when filling components dynamically and to solve this I just had to wrap function with arrow function.

From:

```
{ text: "Delete item", onClick: deleteItem },
```

To:

```
{ text: "Delete item", onClick: (id) => deleteItem(id) },
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice description about this problem and 2 different solution, you can check with this [link](https://duncanleung.com/fixing-react-warning-synthetic-events-in-setstate/)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this link. I chose the solution of "caching the value" before setting the state, over the event.persist() : Just do `const value = event.target.value; setState(value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it using curried function like this.

```
const persistEvent = (fun: any) => (e: any) => {
e.persist();
fun(e);
};
```

now you can write your function like

```
persistEvent(toggleFilter);
```

It's going to be something like this:

```
const persistEvent = (fun: any) => (e: any) => {
    e.persist();
    fun(e);
    };

const delayedFunctionality = (e) => {
  setTimeout(()=> {
     console.log(e.target.value)
  },500
}

<input onChange={persistEvent(delayedFunctionality)} />
```