# Unable to update form field in react via prevState

Tags: reactjs

I have a state variable as:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            fields: {
                applicantName: '',
                applicantType: '',
                applicantAddress: '',
                applicantContact: '',
                buildingName: '',
                buildingAddress: '',
                area:'',
            }
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }
```

and I have a function :

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        fields: {
            ...prevState.fields,     //Unexpected token ..
            {
                event.target.name: event.target.value,
            },
        }
    });
}
```

How I am not able to see any type of syntax here...but my module build fails and it says syntax error near '...'

Comment: still, you are facing the issue or the typo was the issue?

Comment: the typo was only in SO question here, which I have corrected.....but it wasn't the issue

Comment: this.state = { } is inside the constructor right?

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G yes, I have updated the question

Comment: full code here https://pastebin.com/LzVRTbdP

Comment: I checked your code in there, [event.target.name]: e.target.value ( where is e coming from it shoud be event right ? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need return `Object`

```
handleChange(event) {
// note here  => ({
    this.setState((prevSate) => ({
        fields: {
            ...prevState.fields,
//and there ..
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on  Abdullah suggestion, its better when you use `...prevState` for wohle state:

```
handleChange(event) {
// note here  => ({
    this.setState((prevSate) => ({
        // note change here
        ...prevState,
        fields: {
            ...prevState.fields,
//and there ..
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    });
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

based on PraveenRaoChavan comment:

typo fix:
need use `event` not `e`

Comment: this is not the correct solution. What if state have more data other than `fields`

Comment: for this approach its correct. You have edited your answer based on mine. This is not correct

Comment: aah. Alright, I will delete my answer. Kindly update your answer with `...prevState`

PS: DELETED

Comment: @dbvt10 its still not working......please see my full code here https://pastebin.com/LzVRTbdP

Comment: what is e here? Shouldn't it be event? ( or can we write it that way !! )

Comment: hi, with your code my my syntax error is resolved, but when I type on my input field it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null` in `handleChange` function

Comment: yeah same for me.. Trying to debug that :D

Comment: @DeanAmbrose please change your code to reflect this.

Comment: its your problem is resolved, feel free to mark this has an answer and move it up

Comment: I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null in handleChange

Comment: Yeah this ^^^ would be better. Also might sound weird but when i change from callback to `this.setState({...})` it works fine. STRANGE

Comment: @Abdullah as I type a word in my input field my page is reloading ....can you explain why

Comment: Firstly, some light on your last issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089795/reactjs-cant-set-state-from-an-event-with-event-persist


Secondly: When you change some input, it updates the state and when state updates, it re-render the component which causes reloading, read about controlled vs uncontrolled components

Comment: @Abdullah if you can please see here `https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VmmPgp?editors=0010` this example is from offcial docs......I have used this stratergy to maintain controller components..........but here the page is not reloading

Comment: oh boyyyy.. It does re-render for every change.. Just put `    console.log("Rerender")` in render() function and see it yourself. It is not visible to you naked eye because the component is very small unlike you actual component which is little complex.

Comment: @Abdullah i know it renrenders ......but in my case page gets reload  but in the codepen example page does not reload it simply rerenders like ajax call the page does not itself reload just the content gets reloaded

Comment: sorry, i think that is another issue :) open new thread, we lookinkg on it

Comment: @dbvt10 New thread link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494090/page-gets-reload-instead-of-re-render-while-changing-state-in-react

Answer (score 0):

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        fields: {
            ...prevState.fields,
            {
                event.target.name: e.target.value,
            },
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: this is not the correct solution. What if state more key, value pair other than `fields `

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in there

change

```
this.setState((prevSate) => { }
```

to

```
this.setState((prevState) => { }
```