# How to trigger an AJAX call after setState() is effective?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a search page component, that contains a number of inputs to filter the search results.

Each input changes the state of the component, and should trigger an AJAX call to refresh the search results:

```js
handleSearchStringChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        filterSearchString: event.target.value
    });

    loadSearchResults(event.target.value);
}

render() {
    return (
        // ...

        <input type="text" value={this.state.filterSearchString} onChange={this.handleSearchStringChange} />

        // ...
    );
}
```

This is all good, however, as soon as you add more filters, it becomes cumbersome to pass all the filter values to `loadSearchResults()`.

What I'd like to do, is update the state of the component using `setState()` as I do above, and then **have `loadSearchResults()` build the AJAX request from the state alone**.

I can't do this right now, because `setState()` is asynchronous, and doing so would make `loadSearchResults()` use potentially outdated data.

**Is there any way to trigger the AJAX call *after* `setState()` has completed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with the callback from `setState` e.g.

I would also not use `event.target` in the setState call since it [can be nullified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089795/reactjs-cant-set-state-from-an-event-with-event-persist). Instead store it in a local variable

```
let filterSearchString = event.target.value;

this.setState({ filterSearchString }, 
() => loadSearchResults(this.state.filterSearchString) );
```

Comment: Thank you, and for the advice about `event.target` too!

Answer (score 2):

You can do like that. You can read this article who will help you with this case https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

```
handleSearchStringChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        filterSearchString: event.target.value
    }, () => {
       loadSearchResults(event.target.value);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

setState accepts a callback, when it finished with state update:

```
handleSearchStringChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        filterSearchString: event.target.value
    }, () => {
       loadSearchResults(this.state.filterSearchString);
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        // ...

        <input type="text" value={this.props.searchString} onChange={this.handleSearchStringChange} />

        // ...
    );
}
```